# AngularJS: Searching an Array returned from a promise in a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have an AngularJS service, it fetches an array with JSON objects from a server.

In the service, i need a function "getElementByID(ID)" from the list the service fetched. (or get Element by XY)

My problem is, that the list is not there yet when i start searching. It seems that it doesn't work to resolve the promise in the service itself - does it always need to be resolved from outside?

I created a Plunker to describe the problem here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hlyg3mGPi7RKFHmcK1ZM?p=preview

How can i search an array which is a promise in a service?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note: JSON is a data serialization format, you use it to serialize stuff as strings and deserialize them in JS (and other languages) you have an array of JS objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, in order to work on the array - you need to first unwrap the promise with `.then` and then use the fact the return value is another promise.

For example:

```
// return if in a service method
var p = $http.get("http://jsonurl").then(function(result){
    return result.filter(function(el){ return el.id === "foo"});
});

p.then(function(value){
   // value is an array that contains only elements with property `id === "foo"`
});
```

You can for example, create a method that fetches your data once:

```
var data = null;
function getData(){
    return $q.when(data || $http.get("http://jsonurl")).then(function(val){
        return data = val; // cache and return the result;
    }); // either data, or cached data
}
```

Now, you can create a getByPredicate on your service:

```
function get(predicate){
     return getData().then(function(arr){
          return arr.filter(predicate);
     });
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
get(function(el){ return el.id === "foo"; }).then(function(values){
    //values is all the array elements with an id property whose value is foo.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BenjaminGruenbaum ! It sounds logical - but somehow I cannot get it to work. The "Get" function does not return anything from the filter, but the array is already there?! I tried it here in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oiaVYDQiB9kgpm96ptL2?p=preview

Comment: @ulilicht you're calling $resource instead of $http and forgot to do `.$promise` at the end of it to return a promise for the resource. Then, you're also calling .query on the array, don't.

Comment: ok, got it to work thank you very much! Working plunker can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/oiaVYDQiB9kgpm96ptL2?p=preview


One open point: Why is `data` not cached? Shouldn't the service be singleton in angular? You can see 5 get requests in your console at the moment.

Comment: @ulilicht the service is a singleton (sadly) but you're seeing 5 requests because the first one didn't finish by the time the last one went out, you can use a boolean flag to signal waiting if you'd like.